# Terraform Azurerm error: linuxConfiguration.ssh.publicKeys.path is invalid

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am using **Terraform v0.12.24 with provider.azurerm v2.2.0**
I get this error below when i try to create scaleset VMs:

> Error: compute.VirtualMachineScaleSetsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure
>   sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error:
>   Code="InvalidParameter" **Message="The value of parameter
>   linuxConfiguration.ssh.publicKeys.path is invalid."
>   Target="linuxConfiguration.ssh.publicKeys.path"**
>
> on scaleset.tf line 1, in resource
>   "azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set" "demo":    1: resource
>   "azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set" "demo" {

I am using Windows 10 for the terraform configuration. My os_profile_linux_config is as below:

```
       storage_profile_image_reference {
        publisher = "Canonical"
        offer     = "UbuntuServer"
        sku       = "18.04-LTS"
        version   = "latest"
      }

  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = true

    ssh_keys {
      key_data = file("C:/Users/jack/Documents/key/id_rsa.pub")
      path     = "C:/Users/jack/Documents/key"
    }
  }
```

First, i have tried two different key pairs. one is created by puttygen and the other by ssh-keygen with git bash. I had the same error with both of them. 
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your issue, I think you misunderstand the property `path` of the ssh_key, it shows here:

> ssh_keys - (Optional) Specifies a collection of path and key_data to
>   be placed on the virtual machine.

It's the path inside the VM that you want to create, not the path of the machine that you execute the Terraform. And also:

> Note: Please note that the only allowed path is
>   /home//.ssh/authorized_keys due to a limitation of Azure.

Comment: Hi I am having the same (or very similar issue) issue as outlined here could you take a look - happy to bounty if my issue can be resolved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70749060/mongodb-replica-set-the-value-of-parameter-linuxconfiguration-ssh-publickeys-k