# MongoDB Replica Set - The value of parameter linuxConfiguration.ssh.publicKeys.keyData is invalid

Tags: mongodb, azure

This is concerning the Azure Deployment Template for a MongoDB Replica Set defined here [mongodb-replica-set-centos](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/application-workloads/mongo/mongodb-replica-set-centos).

When I run the recommended deployment commands to deploy the replica set, namely

```
az group create --name <resource-group-name> --location <resource-group-location> # Use this command when you need to create a new resource group for your deployment.
az deployment group create --resource-group <my-resource-group> --template-uri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/migr8/AzureDeploymentTemplates/main/mongo/mongodb-replica-set-centos/azuredeploy.json
```

where the resource group is already set up. I receive the following error:

```json
{
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "DeploymentFailed",
    "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "Conflict",
        "message": "{\r\n  \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\r\n    \"details\": [\r\n      {\r\n        \"code\": \"DeploymentFailed\",\r\n        \"message\": \"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.\",\r\n        \"details\": [\r\n          {\r\n            \"code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n  \"message\": \"{\\r\\n  \\\"error\\\": {\\r\\n    \\\"code\\\": \\\"InvalidParameter\\\",\\r\\n    \\\"message\\\": \\\"The value of parameter linuxConfiguration.ssh.publicKeys.keyData is invalid.\\\",\\r\\n    \\\"target\\\": \\\"linuxConfiguration.ssh.publicKeys.keyData\\\"\\r\\n  }\\r\\n}\"\r\n          }\r\n        ]\r\n      }\r\n    ]\r\n  }\r\n}"
      },
      {
        "code": "Conflict",
        "message": "{\r\n  \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\r\n    \"details\": [\r\n      {\r\n        \"code\": \"DeploymentFailed\",\r\n        \"message\": \"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.\",\r\n        \"details\": [\r\n          {\r\n            \"code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n            \"message\": \"{\\r\\n  \\\"error\\\": {\\r\\n    \\\"code\\\": \\\"InvalidParameter\\\",\\r\\n    \\\"message\\\": \\\"The value of parameter linuxConfiguration.ssh.publicKeys.keyData is invalid.\\\",\\r\\n    \\\"target\\\": \\\"linuxConfiguration.ssh.publicKeys.keyData\\\"\\r\\n  }\\r\\n}\"\r\n          }\r\n        ]\r\n      }\r\n    ]\r\n  }\r\n}"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The problem field is in both primary-resources.json and secondary-resources.json appears to be

```json
    "variables": {
        "subnetRef": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('subnet').vnet, parameters('subnet').name)]",
        "securityGroupName": "[concat(parameters('namespace'), parameters('vmbasename'), 'nsg')]",
        "linuxConfiguration": {
            "disablePasswordAuthentication": true,
            "ssh": {
                "publicKeys": [
                    {
                        "path": "[concat('/home/', parameters('adminUsername'), '/.ssh/authorized_keys')]",
                        "keyData": "[parameters('adminPasswordOrKey')]"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
```

And ascociated with the variable `adminPasswordOrKey`. I have tried changing this to be both standard passwords and SSH keys of varying bit-depth, no luck...

> How can I fix this?

#### Repro steps

1. Run `az group create --name <resource-group-name> --location <resource-group-location>` where resource group exists.
2. Run `az deployment group create --resource-group <my-resource-group> --template-uri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/migr8/AzureDeploymentTemplates/main/mongo/mongodb-replica-set-centos/azuredeploy.json` and step through the prompts
3. Enter the relevant in formation.

---

#### Further Investigation

I have just seen this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60860498/626442) saying specifically that

> Note: Please note that the only allowed path is /home//.ssh/authorized_keys due to a limitation of Azure.

I have changed this value of the path, no joy, same error. :'[

Comment: I am happy to bounty whatever is required to get an answer. :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to pass parameters in `az deployment group create ....  --parameters azuredeploy.parameters.json`. You can download [azuredeploy.parameters.json](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/application-workloads/mongo/mongodb-replica-set-centos/azuredeploy.parameters.json) and change values as needed.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-tutorial-use-parameter-file?tabs=azure-cli#deploy-template for details.

Specifically the error in the question complains about `adminUsername` parameter being empty. Bear in mind this user name is also being used in the home directory path, so limit yourself to lowcase ASCII a-z, numbers, underscore. No spaces, not special characters, no utf.

Not related to the error, but be aware these necromancers use mongo 3.2 which was buried 4  years ago: https://www.mongodb.com/support-policy/lifecycles. Considering they open it wide to the internet you may have way more problems if you actually deploy it.

**UPDATE**

An example of the parameters I used:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "adminUsername": {
      "value": "yellow"
    },
    "mongoAdminUsername": {
      "value": "phrase"
    },
    "mongoAdminPassword": {
      "value": "settle#SING"
    },
    "secondaryNodeCount": {
      "value": 2
    },
    "sizeOfDataDiskInGB": {
      "value": 2
    },
    "dnsNamePrefix": {
      "value": "written"
    },
    "centOsVersion": {
      "value": "7.7"
    },
    "primaryNodeVmSize": {
      "value": "Standard_D1_v2"
    },
    "secondaryNodeVmSize": {
      "value": "Standard_D1_v2"
    },
    "zabbixServerIPAddress": {
      "value": "Null"
    },
    "adminPasswordOrKey": {
      "value": "ssh-rsa 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"
    }
  }
}
```

**DANGER**: It will deploy publicly accessible mongodb replica set with publicly accessible credentials, so please delete the resources as soon as you are happy with testing/debugging

This is how deployment looks like on the portal: [image]

Comment: I will try what you say now, thank you for your response. My next step is to upgrade to Mongo 4+ and maybe switch to Ubuntu 20+. Thanks again, will accept once verified.

Comment: I am afraid this is not the answer, the paremters set in those files only fill in what I can provide at the command line. I have updated that file and supplied it as you suggested and I hit the same error. Did you successfully get this to run? Thanks again for your time here...

Comment: You should really update the question with the parameters you put in the file. It complains about invalid data so data is what should be validated. I have added an example of parameters that "worked on my PC", if it helps.

Comment: That is fantastic, it seems that the adminPasswordOrKey value _has_ to be prefixed with "ssh-rsa".

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Ed25519 key type, please note that Microsoft Azure does not currently support Ed25519 SSH keys for virtual machines (VMs). The supported SSH key types for VM authentication in Azure are RSA and DSA key types.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/ed25519-ssh-keys